# Why is Haskell faster than C++ for a simple fibonacci

Tags: c++, performance, haskell

Usually questions in the Haskell tag are why is haskell so slow compared to X. Mostly you can tie that down to usages of `String` instead of `Text` or `ByteString`. Non-strict evaluation or lack of type signatures.

But here I have a simple fibonacci calculator that outperforms C++ by about a factor of 2. This might be either a lack of c++ knowledge - but I got the code from a friend, who used to code more than just a bit in this language.

```
★ g++ -O3 fib2.cc -o cc-fib -lgmpxx -lgmp 
★ time ./cc-fib > /dev/null
./cc-fib > /dev/null  8,23s user 0,00s system 100% cpu 8,234 total

★ ghc -O3 --make -o hs-fib fib1.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( fib1.hs, fib1.o )
Linking hs-fib ...
★ time ./hs-fib > /dev/null
./hs-fib > /dev/null  4,36s user 0,03s system 99% cpu 4,403 total
```

In the haskell file I used just simply a strict `zipWith'` and a strict `add'` function (this is where the extension `BangPatterns` is used - it just tells the compiler to evaluate the arguments `x`/`y` before performing a the addition) as well as adding an explicit type signature.

Both versions use bigint, so this seems comparable to me, also the c++ code does not use the "standard" recursion which has an exponential run-time but a memoized version that should behave nicely (or at least that's what I think - please correct me if I'm wrong).

Setup used is:

- Linux 64-bit (Mint) on a fairly recent laptop
- ghc-7.10.3
- g++ 4.8.4 + libgmp-dev 2:5.1.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1

### `fib.cc`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>

mpz_class fib(int n) {
    mpz_class p1 = 0;
    mpz_class p2 = 1;
    mpz_class result;
    if ( n == 0 ) return 0;
    if ( n == 1 ) return 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n ; i ++ ) {
        result = p1 + p2;
        p1 = p2;
        p2 = result;
    }
    return result;
}

int main () {
    std::cout<<fib(1000000)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### `fib.hs`

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns -#}
module Main where

fib1 :: [Integer]
fib1 = 0:1:zipWith' (add') fib1 (tail fib1)
     where zipWith' :: (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
           zipWith' _ [] _ = []
           zipWith' _ _ [] = []
           zipWith' f (x:xs) (y:ys) = let z = f x y in z:zipWith' f xs ys
           add' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
           add' !x !y = let z = x + y in z `seq` z

fib4 :: [Integer]
fib4 = 0:1:zipWith (+) fib4 (tail fib4)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ fib1 !! 1000000
```

Comment: This seems more like an issue of GMP's design tradeoffs vs your Haskell implementation's Integer, not C++ itself vs Haskell.

Comment: On second thought, you might be doing a bunch of unnecessary copies in the C++. I'm not sure how `mpz_class`'s `operator=` works.

Comment: Quoting from homepage *"GMP is carefully designed to be as fast as possible, both for small operands and for huge operands"* I thought gmp would be the correct choice for a fast implementation. Can you tell more about those design choices?

Comment: @user2357112: GHC uses GMP, so it's probably not that.  (Technically this is only one possible compile-time configuration, but I've never seen any other in practice; the other one I know is "integer-simple" and should be slower.)

Comment: I am using hvr's ppa repository to get ghc, how can I check whether I use the libgmp back end for `Integer`, I actually never needed to check this before.

Comment: You can probably speed up the C++ implementation by replacing `p1 = p2; p2 = result;` with `p1.swap(p2); p2.swap(result);`

Comment: what if you dont print anything from both? same result?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe You are using integer-gmp, it's basically a guarantee unless you put in effort.  If you want to see then just look at the package list: `ghc-pkg list | grep integer`.

Comment: Note that `add'` above is equivalent to `(+)` -- both will force their arguments. Also `seq z z` is the same as `z` -- both will force `z`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given the really huge number you are printing, the poor default performance of iostreams may have something to do with it. Indeed, on my system, putting

```
 std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

at the beginning of `main` improved the time slightly (from 20 seconds to 18).

Also, copying around the huge numbers so much is bound to slow it down. If instead, you update both `p1` and `p2` in each step, there's no need to copy them around. You also only need half as many steps in the loop. Like this:

```
mpz_class fib(int n) {
    mpz_class p1 = 0;
    mpz_class p2 = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n/2 ; i ++ ) {
        p1 += p2;
        p2 += p1;
    }
    return (n % 2) ? p2 : p1;
}
```

This dramatically speeds it up on my system (from 18 seconds to 8).

Of course, to really see how fast it can be done with GMP, you should just use the function that does that:

```
mpz_class fib(int n) {
    mpz_class result;
    mpz_fib_ui(result.get_mpz_t(), n);
    return result;
}
```

This is effectively instantaneous on my machine (and yes, it prints the same 208,989-digit number that the other two methods do).

Comment: `mpz_fib_ui` probably uses a totally different algorithm (like [this Haskell code that computes `fib n` in *O(log n)* steps)](https://gist.github.com/gergoerdi/1d8d9ef77781c6df634edbf7db827744) making the comparison meaningless.

Comment: @Cactus: well yeah, but to be fair it was already pretty meaningless. The two languages weren't doing the same thing to start with.